# AWS CodeBuild kubectl apply -f unable to recognize : Unauthorized

Tags: kubectl, aws-codebuild

**The building process failed with this error:**

```
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:41 Running command kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml 
unable to recognize "simple_jwt_api.yml": Unauthorized 
unable to recognize "simple_jwt_api.yml": Unauthorized 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Command did not exit successfully kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml. Reason: exit status 1
```

**The simple_jwt_api.yml file:**
[simple_jwt_api.yml](https://github.com/Fabio-Ottaviani-Dev/FSND-Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS/blob/master/simple_jwt_api.yml)

**The building script file:**
[buildspec.yml](https://github.com/Fabio-Ottaviani-Dev/FSND-Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS/blob/master/buildspec.yml)

**Build logs:**

```
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:41 Running command kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml 
unable to recognize "simple_jwt_api.yml": Unauthorized 
unable to recognize "simple_jwt_api.yml": Unauthorized 

[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Command did not exit successfully kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml. Reason: exit status 1 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Expanding base directory path: . 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Expanding . 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Expanding file paths for base directory . 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Expanding build.json 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Skipping invalid file path build.json 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED 
[Container] 2019/12/12 08:07:43 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

Answer (score 2):

Buildspec looks good so I have a suspicion your CodeBuild service role has a 'path' in its ARN (/service-role/) which is known to cause issue when authenticating to EKS using iam authenticator.

Can you review this answer from me on another thread that may be helpful:

- [Getting "Unable to recognize \"hello-k8s.yml\": Unauthorized" error when running kubectl apply -f hello-k8s.yml in CodeBuild phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171413/getting-unable-to-recognize-hello-k8s-yml-unauthorized-error-when-running)

Also check the 'authenticator' EKS Control plane log which may provide some clue on 'UnAuthorized' error:

- Amazon EKS Control Plane Logging - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html

Comment: I follow your suggestions:
review you answer (different environmental problems)
see the EKS Control Plane Log, that does not provide more info compared with the above log

do you have some other suggestions?

Comment: Run "aws sts get-caller-identity" command in buildspec and confirm the role returned is mapped to EKS using aws auth configmap (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. However, for me the reason is that for the document "/tmp/aws-auth-patch.yml"

I did not add the roles correctly.

First time, I added it to mapUsers rather than mapRoles.

Secondly, I forgot to replace the ACCOUNT_ID

The third time, I use the wrong format.

- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole
  username: build
  groups:

  - system:masters

It should be

- groups:

  - system:masters
    rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole
    username: build

Then I got the correct result.